# how to call Remote bat script which in turn call cmd using PSExec

Tags: windows, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, psexec

I am struggling please help on this.

I had two windows server A and B need to execute the cmd file in Remote Server B from A
used PSExec but nothing works.

```
  PsExec.exe -accepteula \\machinename -u Domain\user  -p password -s cmd /c C:\tmp\import.bat
```

shows:-

Starting cmd on machine...ice on machine.
The system cannot find the path specified.
cmd exited on machine with error code 3.

If I change like this

```
  PsExec.exe -accepteula \\machinename -u Domain\user  -p password -s -d cmd /c C:\tmp\import.bat
```

shows:_
started with process id but nothing execute any thing I missed.

stop.bat which in turn calls the cmd file like below

```
 call C:\Rad\PS1\import.cmd -f C:\Rad\PS1\a.rddp
```

Comment: you should install psexec tools, run it from the cmd once you are in the pasex directory, 'psexec \\computername -d -i notepad'

Comment: already Psexec installed and run it from there only

Answer (score 0):

If You have at least PowerShell version 2.0 in both servers,

Open PowerShell and try

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName <Computer Name> -ScriptBlock {start-process C:\tmp\import.bat} -credential (Get-Credential)

#Give domain\username and Password when Promted
```

More [about_Remote](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847900.aspx)